# What equivalent addValueEventListener in firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch specific data from Firebase in my Android application. 
Put code

---

```
    DatabaseReference Ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Working").child(FoundID).child("l");
    Ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                               }

        }
```

//

But when used firestore , it is refuse addValueEventListener 
How to do the previous code in firestore not firebase

Answer (score 4):

Firestore is different than real time database, you should read the documentation here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

But the equivalent of `addValueEventListener` is `get()`

From the docs:

> [`public Task<DocumentSnapshot> get ()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#get())
>
> Reads the document referenced by this DocumentReference.

You can retrieve all the documents inside a certain collection, example:

```
db.collection("Working")
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

---

To be able to retrieve data using firestore in realtime, then you can do the following:

```
final DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
docRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
@Override
public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
                    @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
    if (e != null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
        return;
    }

    if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Current data: " + snapshot.getData());
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Current data: null");
     }
   }
});
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen